# Set Value of ComboBoxColumn DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a question. I have a `ComboBoxColumn` and want to populate Data from Database via `ComboBox` Variable inside this `Column`. How can i achieve this.

This snippet I tried doesnt doesn't work

```
ComboBoxColumn.Items.AddRange("One", "Two", "Three", "Four");
```

My problem is i getting Data inside another function that will save all the values inside a ComboBox Variable (that every Functions has Access to) and i want to fill the Cell in DataGridView via Column-/Row-Index like this:

```
private ComboBox ComboBoxItems

private void datagridview_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int col1 = datagridview.Columns["datagridview_col1"].Index;
        int col2 = datagridview.Columns["datagridview_col2"].Index;
        int col3 = datagridview.Columns["datagridview_col2"].Index;

        if ((e.ColumnIndex == col1))
        {

            fill_col2();
        }
        else if ((e.ColumnIndex == col2))
        {
            datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = ComboBoxItems1;

            foreach (var item in ComboBoxItems1.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ComboBoxItems1.Items.Count);
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(section))
            {
                fill_col3();
            }
        }
        else if ((e.ColumnIndex == col3))
        {
            datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = ComboBoxItems2;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error loading Data!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}
```

Has anyone an idea for a good working solution?

Comment: I have two questions. 1) Do you want “each” combo box in “each” row of the grid to contain the same values or different values for each row? 2) Does the data source you are binding to the grid have a field for one of the items in the combo box? In other words, are the combo box items connected to the “grids” data source? Example if the combo box column was for display only (not connected), then the selected combo box items by the user are NOT going to be saved into the data source. Can you clarify this?

Comment: I want each ComboBox in each Row, first ComboBox is equal than if a user selects different values it should only change the row where i changed a combobox. So the first ComboBoxes are always equal. 2) I read the Data from a Database into a DataTable and populate each row inside the Table to a ComboBox Variable which i want to display in ComboBoxColumn.

Comment: I am not following your last comment. Keeping it simple, let’s say you have one data grid view combo box column in a grid. “Each” row in the grid has a combo box cell in that column. From this you can do one of two things… 1) Fill “each” combo box on each row with the “same” values… OR … 2) Fill “each” combo box on each row with “different” values. If the values in each combo box row are the same, then, filling/re-filling “each” combo box every time the user clicks the combo box cell… is unnecessary and wasteful. I will assume you want ALL the combos to contain the same values.

Comment: If the values are all the same, then set the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`’s `DataSource` and it will take care of each individual cell and you only set it ONCE. I assume this is what you mean by … _”I have a ComboBoxColumn and want to populate Data from Database via ComboBox Variable inside this Column”_ … it is unclear what you mean by “via ComboBox”… if you have an existing `ComboBox` “with” an existing `DataSource`… then copy it’s data source to the grids combo box column data source.

Comment: This is all fairly straight forward, however, I still can not tell if the combo box column is supposed to “bind” to a particular “column” in the “grids” data source? If it is, then you will need an additional step to check and make sure the database values are all contained in the combo boxes list of values, otherwise, the grids dreaded `DataError` is almost guaranteed.

Comment: "via ComboBox" i mean i have a Variable of Type `ComboBox` which i want to insert into the `DataGridView` `ComboBoxColumn`. But hank you for you're help i will try. @JohnG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the ComboboxColumn datasource, you can set it while you define the ComboboxColumn.

```
var ComboCol= new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
{
    HeaderText = "ComboCol",
    Name = "ComboCol",
    DataSource = new List<string> {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"}
};
```

Then before fill the combobox with the data from database, you need to convert the cell to `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` first.

```
DataSet ds;
string connetionString = @"Connection String";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From TestTable", conn);
    ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds, "TableName");
}

DataGridViewComboBoxCell ComboCell;

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    int index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["CommonCol1"].Value = row[0];

    ComboCell= (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["ComboCol"]);
    ComboCell.Value = row[1].ToString();
}
```

Hope this can help you.